# Selector not working in android gridview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-view, android-gridview

I set a selector for android Gridview like this

```
mygridview.setSelector(R.drawable.my_background);
```

When i click a child in the gridview it is working fine(background is setting) and the backgroud does not disappear after losing focus from gridview.

But when i manually select a child view like `mygridview.setSelection(position)` it is setting background but **that is disappear when it losing focus from gridview**

by the way my selector is like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#08c246"/>
            <padding android:left="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

i have tried by setting `android:state_selected`  `android:state_checked` but no use.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Use a var to store which one do you select and custom it in getView().

Comment: i want one of the child view of gridview must looks like clicked initially. @tinysunlight

Answer (score 0):

I guess:
    mGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)

```
item.xml
<FrameLayout
android:background = "@drawable/my_background"
>
</FrameLayout>
my_background.xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_selected = "true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#08c246"/>
            <padding android:left="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <padding android:left="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: This doesn't work well. thanks for your interest. i got solution which i will post now

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer

1. Don't set selector in gridview like this `mygridview.setSelector(R.drawable.my_background)`
2. Change drawable like this:

   ```
   <item android:state_activated="true">
       <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="oval">
           <solid android:color="#08c246"/>
           <padding android:left="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:top="-5dp"/>

       </shape>
   </item>
   ```
3. Make above drawable as the background of cellview(The view used to make each cell of gridview)
4. To programatically select a cell from gridview just do `mygridview.setItemChecked(pos, true);`

This worked for me!